# TWTweetComposeViewController Account Choice in Landscape Orientation

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5, twitter

If I present a TWTweetComposeViewController in portrait there is a *From* field that allows a user to choose which account they want to use. However my app is Landscape, and there is no *From* field.

How can a user choose which account to use?

It seems there is not even a way for me to choose which account the composer opens with.